# preg_match strings regardless of proper format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this kind of string format used in a preg_match:

```
[Day][MonthAbbr] [Date] [Hour]:[Minutes][AM/PM]

example:
ThuDec 27 2:00am
```

Having this $pattern and some sort of code:

```
$pattern = "/([A-Z]{2}\w+)([A-Z]{2}\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)(..)/ims";
$match = array();
if (preg_match($pattern, rtrim($date), $match)) {
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($match);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo 'Could not parse date.';
}
```

i was able to extract the Month, Day, Time, etc... from the string..

But i was wondering why i came up with the catch 'Could not parse date.' even if the value being passed was still the same..

I compared the values and the one which has an error:

```
ThuDec 27 2:00am
ThuDec 27  4:30am (gives the error)
```

Here's the screen shot below to make a comparison:

[image: As you can see, it returns empty array!]

Is there something wrong with the pattern ive been using in the preg_match?

Comment: Have you copied and pasted bad value or typed it here yourself? If it is only extra space (ASCII 32) between day and hour then pattern matches it. However if there is non-breaking-space (Unicode U+00A0) it won't be matched by `\s+`

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but try this (slightly modified) regex: `/([a-z]{3})([a-z]{3,4})\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2})\:(\d{1,2})[ap]m/i` I tested it with your problematic string and it seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = "ThuDec 27  4:30am";
$pattern = "/([a-z]{3})([a-z]{3})\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)([a-z]{2})/i";
$match = array();
if (preg_match($pattern, $a, $match)) {
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($match);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo 'Could not parse date.';
}
?>
```

This code works pretty well for me.